# Jquery Mobile data-autodividers

Tags: jquery-mobile

Is there a way to have the auto-dividers sort by last name?

I don't think it should have anything to do with the php code, but I thought I would include it for a reference below:

```
                    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `patients` WHERE `company_id` = " . $user_data['company_id'] . " ORDER BY `patient_lastname`");

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                  echo '<li><a href="' . $row['patient_id'] . '">' . $row['patient_firstname'] . ' ' . $row['patient_lastname'] . '</a><span class="ui-li-count">DOB: ' . $row['patient_dob'] . '</span></li>';
                }
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the sorting in the front-end by selecting the list items and sorting them afterward. In the example below, instead of selecting the text content of the list items, you can select the last-name value.

```
var listContentArray = listViewInstance.find('li').not('.ui-li-divider').get();
listContentArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    var first = $(a).text(),
        second = $(b).text();
    if (first < second) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (first > second) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

Then you can destroy the content of the listViewInstance, re-append the elements in the listContentArray, and finally refresh the listView component.

You can download a fully functional example that does all of this at:

http://appcropolis.com/page-templates/autodividers/

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find a way to display Firstname then Lastname and autodivide by Lastname, so I just replaced the code with:

```
' . $row['patient_lastname'] . ', ' . $row['patient_firstname'] . '
```

which displays: "Lastname, Firstname" and autodivides by Lastname. It'll have to work for now.